# How can I do a beautiful enumerating as in URL link?

Tags: enumerate, tikz-styles

How can I do a beautiful enumerating as in URL link?
https://www.freepik.com/free-vector/bullet-points-numbers-button-style-from-one-twelve_6234346.htm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hope this is close enough.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc, fadings}

\begin{document}


\ExplSyntaxOn

\clist_new:N \g_enum_colors_clist
\clist_gset:Nn \g_enum_colors_clist {
    ff7a01, 1a428a, 080808, fe065a,
    007541, fd2300, 5f5f5f, d00204,
    0282fd, 4c1278, 229118, 02195f
}

\int_new:N \g_enum_count_int


\newcommand{\resetenumcount}{
    \int_gset:Nn \g_enum_count_int {1}
}

\newcommand{\increnumcount}{
    \int_gincr:N \g_enum_count_int
    \int_compare:nNnT {\g_enum_count_int} > {\clist_count:N \g_enum_colors_clist} {
        \resetenumcount
    }
}

\cs_set_eq:NN \define_color:nnn \definecolor
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \define_color:nnn {nno}

\newcommand{\setenumcolor}{
    \tl_set:Nx \l_tmpa_tl {\clist_item:Nn \g_enum_colors_clist {\g_enum_count_int}}
    \define_color:nno {enumcolor}{HTML}{\l_tmpa_tl}
}

\AtBeginEnvironment{enumerate}{
    \resetenumcount
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\pgfdeclarelayer{bg}    % declare background layer
\pgfsetlayers{bg,main} % set the order of the layers (main is the standard layer)

\newcommand{\blpt}[1]{%
\setenumcolor\increnumcount%
\raisebox{-1ex}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}%
\node[circle, fill=white, inner sep=1pt] (num) at (0mm, 0mm) {\fontfamily{qhv}\small\selectfont\bfseries #1};
\begin{pgfonlayer}{bg}
\node[rounded rectangle, 
minimum width=3.2em, 
minimum height=1.8em, 
xshift=-0.3em,
shading = axis,
shading angle=135,
left color=enumcolor,
right color=enumcolor!40!white
] (num) at (0mm, 0mm) {};
\end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}}%
}


\begin{minipage}{0.45\linewidth}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\protect\blpt{\arabic*}]
\item abcdefg
\item abcdefg
\item abcdefg
\item abcdefg
\item abcdefg
\item abcdefg
\item abcdefg
\item abcdefg
\item abcdefg
\item abcdefg
\item abcdefg
\item abcdefg
\item abcdefg
\item abcdefg
\end{enumerate}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.45\linewidth}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\protect\blpt{\arabic*}]
\item abcdefg
\item abcdefg
\item abcdefg
\item abcdefg
\item abcdefg
\item abcdefg
\item abcdefg
\item abcdefg
\item abcdefg
\item abcdefg
\item abcdefg
\item abcdefg
\item abcdefg
\item abcdefg
\end{enumerate}
\end{minipage}


\end{document}
```

Comment: You've both been very good.

Answer (score 5):

Her is a slightly modified version, based on [@AlanXiang's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/557415/79060).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xcolor}
%\usepackage{expl3} % since latex 2020-02, expl3 is packed in latex
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{multicol}

\usetikzlibrary{fadings}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\clist_new:N \c_enum_colors_clist
\clist_gset:Nn \c_enum_colors_clist {
    ff7a01, 1a428a, 080808, fe065a,
    007541, fd2300, 5f5f5f, d00204,
    0282fd, 4c1278, 229118, 02195f
}
\int_new:N \c_enum_color_count_int
\int_set:Nn \c_enum_color_count_int {\clist_count:N \c_enum_colors_clist}

\int_new:N \l_enum_count_int


\newcommand{\resetenumcount}{
  \int_gset:Nn \l_enum_count_int {1}
}

\newcommand{\increnumcount}{
  \int_gincr:N \l_enum_count_int
  \int_compare:nNnT {\l_enum_count_int} > {\c_enum_color_count_int} {
    \resetenumcount
  }
}

\newcommand{\setenumcolor}{
  \exp_args:Nnnx \definecolor {enumcolor} {HTML}
    { \clist_item:Nn \c_enum_colors_clist {\l_enum_count_int} }
}

\AtBeginEnvironment{enumerate}{
    \resetenumcount
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\def\enumwd{1.35em} % half the width of rounded rectangle
\def\enumht{.9em}   % half the height
\newcommand{\blpt}[1]{%
  \setenumcolor\increnumcount
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(num.base)]
    \fill[
      rounded corners=.9em,
      left color=enumcolor,
      right color=enumcolor!40!white
    ] (0, 0) rectangle (2*\enumwd, 2*\enumht);
    \coordinate (o) at (2*\enumwd-\enumht, \enumht);
    \fill[enumcolor!30] (o) -- +(\enumht, 0) arc[radius=\enumht, start angle=0, end angle=90] -- cycle;
    \fill[white] (o) circle (.6em);
    \node[
      anchor=center,
      font=\fontfamily{qhv}\fontsize{6}{6}\selectfont\bfseries\color{enumcolor},
      xshift=.25pt,
    ] (num) at (o) {\ifnum#1<10\relax 0#1\else#1\fi};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{3}
  \begin{enumerate}[label=\protect\blpt{\arabic*}]
  \item abcdefg
  \item abcdefg
  \item abcdefg
  \item abcdefg
  \item abcdefg
  \item abcdefg
  \item abcdefg
  \item abcdefg
  \item abcdefg
  \item abcdefg
  \item abcdefg
  \item abcdefg
  \item abcdefg
  \item abcdefg
  \item abcdefg
  \end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Nice! Love the attention to details.

Comment: I hadn't seen these answers that deserve attention and reward for excellent work.